# Is there a special reason why ferns are so early in evolution?

Tags: botany

Reading about plants in history it seems that ferns where already in the Devonian period (400 million years ago) growing. Probably the climate in that time was very different from now, but what made them so good surviving in that time?

Comment: Could be due to them "having" Neochrome, a protein which enables them to respond simultaneously to red and blue light in both the way that they grow and the way the photosynthetic elements in their cells, the chloroplasts, organise themselves. I'd recommend reading into http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21600856-survival-ferns-present-depended-ancient-accident-time-and (mostly about why fern survived for so long) and http://www.britannica.com/plant/fern (general information about fern) and https://u.osu.edu/eeob3320/category/ferns/ (properties of fern)